# Loading datatable(jquery) with ajax after page load AND/OR let the images load first

Tags: ajax, jquery, datatables

Hey guys.  I have an Ajax-loaded data table.  The load goes fine but the one thing I notice is the text on the page is loaded but the header image and footer image is loaded after the Ajax call.  This looks a little weird on the page.  I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this.  I know about the setTimeOut method in jQuery but baffled on how to use that with data tables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var selected;
    var selectedOutput;
    var template;
    var submitButton;

    var insertedTable =  $('#pkgLineTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": '@{Overview.getPkgLineList()}',
        "fnServerData": fnServerObjectToArray(['shortname', 'description'])             
    });
});

  fnServerObjectToArray = function (aElements) {     

    return function (sSource, aaData, fnCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aaData,
            "success": function (json) {
                var a = [];
                $.each(json, function(index, item) {     
                    var inner = [];
                    for (var i = 0, iLen = aElements.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                        inner.push(item[aElements[i]]);
                    }
                    a.push(inner);
                });
                json.aaData = a;
                fnCallback(json);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the ajax after the images have finished, use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of .ready:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var selected;
    var selectedOutput;
    var template;
    var submitButton;
```